# Bottom Navigation with Drawer Layout | onBackPressed in Fragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, bottomnavigationview

I have an interesting and confusing question.

I have a `Drawer Layout` that opens from the `Bottom Navigation` like in the photo

**Screens:**
[image]

In order for `Drawer Layout` to open from the `Bottom Navigation`, I used this code:

```
    bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.itemDrawer -> {
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END)
                    return@setOnItemSelectedListener false
                }
                R.id.homeFragment -> navController.navigate(R.id.homeFragment)
                R.id.booksFragment -> navController.navigate(R.id.booksFragment)
                R.id.grammarFragment -> navController.navigate(R.id.grammarFragment)
                R.id.translatorFragment -> navController.navigate(R.id.translatorFragment)
            }
            true
        }
```

This is what my problem is

When I override listener for Bottom Navigation, in my opinion, the `onBackPressed` behaviour gets confused default.

I mean that when I click on `Home`, then another element, then `Home` again, and so on several times, and I stay on the `Home Fragment` and click on `onBackPressed`, then instead of leaving the app, I go back to the fragment where I was before

I think this is not normal for the user

What should I do?

I thought to somehow override `onBackPressed` for `Home Fragment` but I don't understand how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onBackPressedDispatcher` in your `HomeFragment`

```
private lateinit var onBackPressedCallback: OnBackPressedCallback
```

and instantiate the implementation and add the callback to `activity` in `onResume()`

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    onBackPressedCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                activity?.moveTaskToBack(true)
                exitProcess(ZERO)
            }
        }
    
    activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(onBackPressedCallback)
}
```

Due to this callback added on `activity`, then the callback should be removed on leaving `HomeFragment`

```
override fun onPause() {
    onBackPressedCallback.remove()
    super.onPause()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have already tried with `addCallback`, but the problem is that when I switch to another fragment, this `сallback` remains, and it turns out that my app can be closed from all fragments.

Comment: Should I somehow remove this `callback` when the fragment is closed? How can i do this?

Comment: Yeah, need to add `remove()` for the callback as well, I've updated the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Everything is as in the selected answer, but need to remove this `callback` in the `onPause` of this `fragment`. To prevent the app from closing from all fragments

**1. Create a variable for `callback`**

```
private lateinit var mCallback: OnBackPressedCallback
```

**2. In `onViewCreated` :**

```
mCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                activity?.moveTaskToBack(true)
                exitProcess(0)
            }
        }

activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(mCallback)
```

**3. Remove `callback` when closing the `fragment`**

```
 override fun onPause() {
        mCallback.remove()
        super.onPause()
    }
```